# List Scheduled Queries in BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a need to (programatically) analyse the details of Scheduled Queries in BigQuery (eg which tables are updated and which tables accessed in the SQL). I have done something similar for the BQ Tables/Views using Apps Script `BigQuery.Tables.list()`, but I cannot find an API to access the Scheduled Queries.

The UI is able to list them, so I feel this should be possible programmatically, e.g. via a REST API. Does anyone know if this is possible, what interface is supported (Apps Script, REST ...), and possibly an example of how to use it.

Comment: Just because something can be done in a Google product's UI does not mean Google exposes that functionality programmatically to the public.

Comment: Is this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list it?

Comment: I did look at **Jobs: list**, but it looks like it is for interrogating jobs that have been issues but not yet started (pending), running jobs, and finished jobs. I don't think it has info about Scheduled Queries ... not until it is triggered and becomes a job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scheduled queries are part of BigQuery's Data Transfer Service so you have to use its API. In particular, the [`projects.transferConfigs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.transferConfigs/list) method. Fill in the `dataSourceIds` field with `scheduled_query` and `parent` with `projects/PROJECT_ID`. As discussed in the comments, if you are using a regional location such as europe-west2 instead of a multi-regional one (EU or US) you should use [`projects.locations.transferConfigs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/list) instead. Now, parent resource will be in the form of `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGIONAL_LOCATION`.

In addition, for other transfers you can get the corresponding `dataSourceIds` using the [`projects.dataSources.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.dataSources/list) method. That's how I got the `scheduled_query` one.

Response will be an array of scheduled queries such as:

```
{
  "name": "projects/<PROJECT_NUMBER>/locations/us/transferConfigs/<TRANSFER_CONFIG_ID>",
  "destinationDatasetId": "<DATASET>",
  "displayName": "hacker-news",
  "updateTime": "2018-11-14T15:39:18.897911Z",
  "dataSourceId": "scheduled_query",
  "schedule": "every 24 hours",
  "nextRunTime": "2019-04-19T15:39:00Z",
  "params": {
    "write_disposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
    "query": "SELECT @run_time AS time,\n  title,\n  author,\n  text\nFROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`\nLIMIT\n  1000",
    "destination_table_name_template": "hacker_daily_news"
  },
  "state": "SUCCEEDED",
  "userId": "<USER_ID>",
  "datasetRegion": "us"
}
```

Example of an API call with bash and `curl`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# parameter(s)
location=europe-west2

authToken="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
projectId=$(gcloud config get-value project 2>\dev\null)

# API call
scheduled_queries=$(curl  -H "Authorization: Bearer $authToken" \
https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$projectId/locations/$location/transferConfigs?dataSourceIds=scheduled_query)

# pretty print results
echo $scheduled_queries | python -m json.tool
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks more promising, using the 'TRY API' pane on the projects.dataSources.list page gives expected results including a data source of `projects/my_project/dataSources/scheduled_query`. However, doing the same for projects.transferConfigs.list returns empty results, yet I know there are dozens of Scheduled Queries in Big Query. Think there may still be a gap in my understanding.

Comment: The most likely thing is that you are using a [regional location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#regional_locations) such as `europe-west2` instead of a multi-regional one (`EU` or `US`). If that's the case you should use [`projects.locations.transferConfigs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/list) instead.Now, `parent` resource will be `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGIONAL_LOCATION`.

Comment: Woo hoo, that's the piece of info I was missing. I now have a complete list of all scheduled queries for the BQ project I'm using. Many thanks, saved me hours of manual (error prone) copying from the screen!

Comment: Cool, glad to be of help! feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are excellent responses for using the REST API.  For completeness, I'd like to include the CLI commands approach for solving the same thing.  Personally I find this better suited for shell scripts but YMMV.

Example: List of Schedule Queries from Default Project.

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson
```

Example: Details of a Schedule Query from Default Project.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson --transfer_config [RESOURCE_NAME]
# RESOURCE_NAME is a value you can get from the above bq ls command.
```

[Further details can be found here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell script that will notify you in Slack if any of your scheduled queries fail. Simply integrate into your existing workflow (as blocking or non blocking) or have it on a separate Cron job. I have used httpie to send my HTTP post but you can also use curl or others. Also, you can also change your HTTP post for any other action.

See [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/TransferState) for potential states of transfer state object

```
#1/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install httpie

location=US
authToken="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
projectId=$(gcloud config get-value project 2>\dev\null)

scheduled_queries=$(curl  -H "Authorization: Bearer $authToken" https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$projectId/locations/$location/transferConfigs?dataSourceIds=scheduled_query)

# pretty print results
echo $scheduled_queries | python -m json.tool

length=$(echo "$scheduled_queries" | grep FAILED)
if [ $length -gt 0 ]; then
    echo A SCHEDULED TRANSFER HAS FAILED
    http POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/<your slack channel> text="A SCHEDULED TRANSFER HAS FAILED: HERE IS STDOUT  >>> $scheduled_queries"

else
    echo No errors in scheduled transfers
fi
```

If running outside the cloud or on something that hasn't already authenticated, you will need to authenticate before hand. To do this use before the above:

```
echo $PROD_KEY >> temp_json.json
bash gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=temp_json.json --project=$PROJ_NAME_PROD
```

where $PROD_KEY is the service key for whatever you are trying to access.