# How do I list my scheduled queries via the Python google client API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api

I have set up my service account and I can run queries on bigQuery using `client.query()`.

I could just write all my scheduled queries into this new `client.query()` format but I already have many scheduled queries so I was wondering if there is a way I can get/list the scheduled queries and then use that information to run those queries from a script.

[image: I can query with big Query but I want to list queries]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the APIs. When you don't know which one to use, I have a tip. Use the command proposed by @Yev

`bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson`

But log the API calls. for that use the `--apilog <logfile name>` parameter like that

`bq --apilog ./log ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson`

And, magically, you can find the API called by the command:
`https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/US/transferConfigs?alt=json`

Then, a simple google search leads you to the [correct documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/list)

---

In python, add that dependencies in your `requirements.txt`: `google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer` and use that code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
parent = client.common_project_path("<PROJECT-ID>")
resp = client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)
print(resp)
```

Comment: oh nice! i  but I dont get why you suggest logging?

Comment: It's my trick to understand how the CLI work. In the future, if want to understand another command, you can use it

Comment: Great answer! If your scheduled queries aren't located in `US`, which is the default here, you can explicitly set the location like so: `client.common_project_path("<PROJECT-ID>" + "/locations/EU")`

Answer (score 2):

Using cloud SDK there is a command that gets you what you want and more:
`bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson`, more about that here - [List Scheduled Queries in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745763/list-scheduled-queries-in-bigquery)

Executing this within your command prompt (given google cloud SKD is installed) gives you the following (with red part = scheduled query sql):

[image]

---

Following that you can run this as a shell sub process within Python and parse it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from subprocess import PIPE, run, call

response = run('bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson', 
               stdout=PIPE, 
               stderr=PIPE, 
               universal_newlines=True, 
               shell=True)

response
```

Here is first few lines resulting from above:

```
CompletedProcess(args='bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson', returncode=0, stdout='[\n  {\n    "dataSourceId": "scheduled_query",\...
```

Then to get to sql you could access output via `response.stdout` and parse as json and then dictionary your way in to desired results or get it into pandas dataframe format and go from there like below:

```
data = json.loads(response.stdout)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

df.columns =

```
dataSourceId
datasetRegion
destinationDatasetId
disabled
displayName
name
schedule
state
updateTime
userId
emailPreferences.enableFailureEmail
params.destination_table_name_template

### sql located in this one
params.query

params.write_disposition
scheduleOptions.startTime
params.overwrite_destination_table
params.source_dataset_id
params.source_project_id
scheduleOptions.endTime
nextRunTime
```

Answer (score 1):

With python you can do:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

bq_datatransfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

parent = 'projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/EU'
resp_datatransfers = bq_datatransfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)

datatransfers = list(resp_datatransfers)
```

Link to documentation: [`.list_transfer_configs()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.services.data_transfer_service.DataTransferServiceClient#google_cloud_bigquery_datatransfer_v1_services_data_transfer_service_DataTransferServiceClient_list_transfer_configs)

Answer (score 0):

It might be me, but I had a hard time finding python documentation on using the bigquery datatransfer API (= scheduled queries).

In python you can do:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer

bq_datatransfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
request_datatransfers = bigquery_datatransfer.ListTransferConfigsRequest(
    # if US, you can just do parent='projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
    parent='projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/EU',  
)

# this method will also deal with pagination
response_datatransfers = bq_datatransfer_client.list_transfer_configs(
    request=request_datatransfers)

# to convert the response to a list of scheduled queries
datatransfers = list(response_datatransfers)
```

Below are some useful resources on the API:

Specifically on the `.list_transfer_configs()` method:

- https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.services.data_transfer_service.DataTransferServiceClient#google_cloud_bigquery_datatransfer_v1_services_data_transfer_service_DataTransferServiceClient_list_transfer_configs

On the `ListTransferConfigsRequest` class:

- https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.ListTransferConfigsRequest

Code snippets and examples on how to use the python API:

- https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/tree/main/samples/snippets

Some official documentation on the use of the API:

- https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/

Answer (score 0):

to get any specific column:

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson|jq -r ".[]|[.name,.displayName,.dataSourceId,.state,.userId]|@csv"|tr -d "\""
```